# Set some Method options for NDSolve globally while allowing others to change

Tags: differential-equations, options

In a code base that is difficult to change for unrelated issues, I have many invocations of `NDSolve` that look like the following:

```
NDSolve[equations, variables, {t, 0, 100}, 
 Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "StiffnessTest" -> False}]
```

This has stopped working with *Mathematica* 9.0, because something is timing out (our problem appears similar to the one described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21946/ndsolve-does-not-respond)). The fix is to change the invocation to look like this:

```
NDSolve[eqns, vars, {t, 0, 100},
  Method -> 
   {"ExplicitRungeKutta", 
    "StiffnessTest" -> False, 
    "EquationSimplification"->"Solve"}]
```

I would like to be able to change the part of the `Method` option involving `"EquationsSimplification"` to `"Solve"` globally, in such a way that it won't be clobbered when a call leaves that option alone, but sets other options (like using the `"ExplicitRungeKutta"` method, or turning off `"StiffnessTest"`). This will allow me to fix things in an init.m file once and for all.

(Yes, I'm aware this is ugly and hacky, but the other approaches are probably less appealing.)

Comment: FWIW, this (unlike e.g. `"StiffnessTest"`) is not an option for any function in the `NDSolve\`` context. So, it looks like you have to insert it at the top level.

Answer (score 2):

So far, it's looking like we'll have to fall back on the common yet awful, fragile and hard-to-maintain solution of putting the following in our `init.m` files:

```
Unprotect[NDSolve];
NDSolve[before___,
   (Method -> meth_), after___] :=
  NDSolve[before,
    (Method ->
      Switch[meth,
       _String,
       {meth, "EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"},
       _List,
       Append[meth, "EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"]
       ]),
    after] /;
   ! FreeQ[meth, "ExplicitRungeKutta"] && 
    FreeQ[meth, "EquationSimplification" -> _];
Protect[NDSolve];
```

I'd really like to be able to solve this problem in almost any other way. At the risk of editorializing a little, I'm pretty displeased that the switch to Mathematica 9 has put us in the position of having to consider doing things like this, by breaking perfectly good, working code.

**EDIT** to improve the function a little based on @Teake Nutma's suggestion, so it's a little more robust.

Comment: I think this is the best way to go. You might improve robustness by throwing `eqns_,ivars_,dvar_,before_` into a single `before___`, and throw in an `If[$VersionNumber >= 9., ...]` statement, but otherwise I don't see much room for improvement.