# PDE raises NDSolve::ntdvdae, then kernel quits

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, crash

In a [related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21946/ndsolve-does-not-respond/21963#21963), the `SolveDelayed->True` option seemed to solve the problem. `SolveDelayed` is not a valid option in M10 (at least not the Student Edition). Any other suggestions?

```
{λ = 1, μ = 0.2, δ = 0.08, η = 0.9, β = 0.8, n = 2};
A = SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; i < j -> η, {i_, j_} /; i > j -> β, {i_, i_} -> 1}, {n, n}];
b[i_, x_] := λ x[[i]];
d[i_, x_] := (μ + δ A[[i]].x) x[[i]];
H[x_, y_] := Sum[b[i, x] (Exp[y[[i]]] - 1) + d[i, x] (Exp[-y[[i]]] - 1), {i, n}];

sol = NDSolve[{
    0 == H[{x[1], x[2]}, D[U[x[1], x[2]], {{x[1], x[2]}, 1}]],
    U[0, x[2]] == 0,
    U[x[1], 0] == 0
   }, U, {x[1], 0, 10}, {x[2], 0, 10}]
```

Comment: According to a Wolfram Community [post](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/412961?p_p_auth=1Q7wEYla), `SetDelayed` is legal but deprecated.  Indeed, the code runs for a while with this option included, even though it is red until the code runs.  However, whether `SetDelayed` is `True` or `False`, the Kernel terminates.  For `True`, `Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>` message appears.  For `False`, nothing appears.  Note that derivatives in this PDE appear in exponentials.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I think you meant `SolveDelayed` instead of `SetDelayed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the Kernel terminates, because it does not like `x[1]` and `x[2]` in this context.  When I modify the code to

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{0 == H[{x1, x2}, D[U[x1, x2], {{x1, x2}, 1}]], 
   U[0, x2] == 0, U[x1, 0] == 0}, U, {x1, 0, 10}, {x2, 0, 10}]
```

it gives the same warning message,

```
NDSolveValue::ntdvdae: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. NDSolve will try solving the system as differential-algebraic equations. >>
```

but the Kernel does not terminate.  Instead, the code produces an `InterpolatingFunction` that is identically zero.  Indeed, `U = 0` satisfies `H[{x1, x2}, {0, 0}] == 0` with homogeneous boundary conditions, so `U = 0` is the correct answer.

**Update**

As pointed out by Michael E2 in a Comment below, `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}` eliminates the warning message.

Comment: I remember this issue of indexed variables arising somewhere else, but I can't find the right search terms.

Comment: Why not point out `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}`, the solution suggested in the community post you linked to in your comment above?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Not sure whether your comment was meant for me, but I acted on it by trying it and then editing my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the second comment was meant for you, and you're welcome! (+1 already.)  The first was general.  It would be nice to link the questions.

Comment: Back to the drawing board on my boundary conditions, I suppose ... never do get those right.

Comment: @Ian I recommend that you report this to Wolfram Inc as a bug.  Under no circumstances should the Kernel crash.